# preg_match is matching a NULL subject

Tags: php, regex

I have a `preg_match` in a switch/case that is matching a NULL subject, and I don't understand why.

Here's my code:

```
switch ( $page_type ) {
    case ( preg_match('/^assets_?.*/', $page_type ) ? true : false ):
        // code
        break;
}
```

`$page_type` is usually a string, but I've found some cases where it can be NULL. For some reason the ternary here is returning true
in one of those cases, so the code inside the case is run.

I realize that I could fix this by checking for a NULL value before the switch, but could someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `$page_type` is `NULL`, `preg_match()` will return `0`, and the ternary will return `false`. In this case it's equivalent to:

```
switch (null) {
    case false:
        //code
        break;
    }
}
```

Since `null == false`, this case is executed.

Don't use `switch` if you need to test a complex condition instead of exact match, write an ordinary `if` statement:

```
if (preg_match('/^assets_?.*/', $page_type )) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Barmar. That was my thought too, so I tried something like `case ( preg_match('/^assets_?.*/', $page_type ) === 1 ? true : false ):` and got the same result. Shouldn't something like that fix the conditional?

Comment: You don't understand how `switch/case` works. You don't put conditions in a `case`, you put exact matches there. `case X:` is short for `if ($page_type == X)`

Comment: So when you do that, you're still testing `if ($page_type == true)` or `if ($page_type == false)` depending on the result of the `preg_match()`.